# bootstrap framework - have at least one accordion (aka collapse) item open at all times

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm using Bootstrap on my site and just added an accordion aka collapse to some page content.

It works fine but I'd like to keep **at least one panel open at all times**.

Currently, the panels always toggle open/close, see the example below:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse

Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Here is the code from the Boostrap site that's similar to my current implementation (initializing it using data attributes):

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I have the same concern.  Please post if you find a solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Also having the same issue. like @MattJohnson I have tried the solution of trying to prevent the default hide event but had no luck.

Comment: possible duplicate, solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725717/how-do-you-make-twitter-bootstrap-accordion-keep-one-group-open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to this question here:
[How do you make Twitter Bootstrap Accordion keep one group open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725717/how-do-you-make-twitter-bootstrap-accordion-keep-one-group-open)

Thanks @aron.lakatos for pointing out the other solved question.  While questions are same, the solved one was asked a few weeks after this question here :)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/SMT9D/61/

```
$('.accordion-toggle').on('click',function(e){
    if($(this).parents('.accordion-group').children('.accordion-body').hasClass('in')){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

You should add `e.preventDefault();` **to prevent the default behaviour of `#` HTML anchor if you have a scroll in your page**

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent Bootstrap from doing anything when somebody clicks on the active group.

Search in bootstrap-collapse.js for the function which handles this.

Have you had look at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse > Usage > Options?

Comment: The only thing it describes that seems promising is the `hide` event.  One would think you could just handle the event and return false, but that doesn't work consistently.

Comment: jus add class="accordion-body collapse in" instead of class="accordion-body collapse".
on adding "in" the group will remain open.