# How do you make Twitter Bootstrap Accordion keep one group open?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to mimic the Outlook bar using Twitter bootstrap using the accordion and collapse plugin, so far I got the collapse and accordion working, but it presently allows for all sections to be collapsed.

I would like to limit it so that one and only one is always shown.

Here is the one I am working on: http://jsfiddle.net/trajano/SMT9D/ and I think it's somewhere along the lines of

```js
$('#accordions').on('hide', function (event) {
  console.warn("HIDE TRIGGERED, check if trying to hide the active one if so stop");
})
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Here is an easy way to do it:

### Bootstrap 4

```js
$('.accordion .btn-link').on('click', function(e) { 
  if (!$(this).hasClass('collapsed')) { 
    e.stopPropagation(); 
  } 
});
```

from @mr_joncollette in the comments

### Bootstrap 3

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dozoisch/SMT9D/45/) for Bootstrap 3.**

*Code for Bootstrap 3:*

```js
$('.panel-heading a').on('click',function(e){
    if($(this).parents('.panel').children('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in')){
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    // You can also add preventDefault to remove the anchor behavior that makes
    // the page jump
    // e.preventDefault();
});
```

The code checks if the clicked element is the one that is currently shown *(by the class "in")* and if it does have the "in" class, it stops the hiding process.

---

### Deprecated Bootstrap 2

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dozoisch/SMT9D/2/) for Bootstrap 2.**

*Code for Bootstrap 2:*

```js
$('.accordion-toggle').on('click',function(e){
    if($(this).parents('.accordion-group').children('.accordion-body').hasClass('in')){
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    // You can also add preventDefault to remove the anchor behavior that makes
    // the page jump
    // e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

**Note:** *Be careful if you want to attach more click events on the accordion, since the `e.stopPropagation()` will block events that would occur after the check.*

Comment: thank you for this! didn't use the exact same solution, but `e.stopPropagation()` was what i needed!

Comment: Nice
add e.preventDefault(); after if statement and your page won't jump on click

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Beautiful — works with Bootstrap 4.5 `$('.accordion .btn-link').on('click', function(e) { if (!$(this).hasClass('collapsed')) { e.stopPropagation(); } });`

Answer (score 13):

***Updated 2018***

Here's how to keep at least open in both Bootstrap v3 or v4. This means that **the open accordion can *only* be closed by toggling another one open**.

**Bootstrap 4**

https://www.codeply.com/go/bbCcnl0jBB

```
// the current open accordion will not be able to close itself
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click',function(e){
    if ( $(this).parents('.accordion').find('.collapse.show') ){
        var idx = $(this).index('[data-toggle="collapse"]');
        if (idx == $('.collapse.show').index('.collapse')) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
});
```

Also, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49489539/171456) which shows how to specify a "default" accordion that will open when all others are closed.

---

**Bootstrap 3**

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click',function(e){
    if($(this).parents('.panel').find('.collapse').hasClass('in')){
        var idx = $(this).index('[data-toggle="collapse"]');
        var idxShown = $('.collapse.in').index('.accordion-body');
        if (idx==idxShown) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
});
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/yLw944BrgA

```
<div class="accordion" id="myAccordion">
    <div class="panel">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-1" data-parent="#myAccordion">Question 1?</button>
        <div id="collapsible-1" class="collapse">
            ..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-2" data-parent="#myAccordion">Question 2?</button>
        <div id="collapsible-2" class="collapse">
            ..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-3" data-parent="#myAccordion">Question 3?</button>
        <div id="collapsible-3" class="collapse">
           ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(***Note:*** the `panel` class is needed in Bootstrap 3 to [make the accordion behavior work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425165/bootstrap-3-accordion-button-toggle-data-parent-not-working/19426220#19426220))

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50206963/how-to-restrict-accordion-to-open-only-one-panel-at-a-time

Comment: The example for B4 is not working for some reason, even on codeply.

Answer (score 10):

I want to precise @Hugo Dozois 's answer

http://jsfiddle.net/SMT9D/61/

You should add `e.preventDefault();` **to prevent the default behaviour of `#` HTML anchor if you have a scroll in your page**

```
$('.panel-heading a').on('click',function(e){
    if($(this).parents('.panel').children('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in')){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Or you can use simple CSS trick as follows:

```
/*
prevent the active panel from collapsing
 */
.panel-group [aria-expanded=true]{
  /*
  http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events
  Works for MOST modern browsers. (- Opera Mobile)
  */
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

must have proper tags on the inactive panel links

```
 aria-expanded="false"
```

Comment: It works, but for already not-collapsed elements, it won't. Only in the second action.

Answer (score 8):

As all the other JS answers use an [inadvisable](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/) `stopPropagation()` here is my solution using just the native Bootstrap events (tested on Bootstrap 4).

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chris_h/aq9Laaew/260760/)**

```
$('#accordionExample').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).data('isShowing', true);
});

$('#accordionExample').on('hide.bs.collapse', function (event) {
    if (!$(this).data('isShowing')) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    $(this).data('isShowing', false);
});
```

It makes use of the fact that a click on a collapsed element will result in a `show.bs.collapse` followed by a `hide.bs.collapse`. Whereas a click on the open element will result in just a `hide.bs.collapse`.

Answer (score 2):

None of the provided solutions allow to have more than one accordion in the same page, keeping or not one *tab* opened.

Here's mine solution:

```
$("[data-toggle=buttons][data-oneopen=true] [data-toggle=collapse]").on("click", function (e) {
  var me = $(this);
  var target = $(me.attr("data-target") || me.attr("href"));
  if (target.hasClass("show")) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

First I've chosen a `data-oneopen` attribute to flag those accordion buttons to enable this behaviour, but it can be replaced for a class or any other selector.

Then I check `data-target` and `href` attributes to find related *tab*.

Finally I `stopPropagation` if the item has `show` class, just change it for a `in` class to have a solution for Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 2):

**Bootstrap 5**

Omit the `data-bs-parent` attribute on each `.accordion-collapse` to make accordion items stay open when another item is opened.

Comment: This solution does not apply to the question "Keep one group open" because it still allows collapsing the only one opened keeping none opened

Answer (score 2):

**Solution for Bootstrap-5**

```
$(this).on('mouseenter', function (e) {
    if( !$(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
        $(this).attr('data-bs-toggle','disabled');
    }
})
$(this).on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    if( !$(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
        $(this).attr('data-bs-toggle','collapse');
    }
})
```

Hope it helps Andreas

Comment: you can also use the show.bs.collapse and hide.bs.collapse events to enable/disable the buttons. especially on touch screens

Answer (score 1):

## Bootstrap 4.0

```
$('.card').click(function(e) {
  if (
    $(this)
      .find('.collapse')
      .hasClass('show')
  ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

This code block checks if the clicked card is collapsed (by looking at the div with the class `collapse`). When the card is currently `show`n it stops [propagating the event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Comment: I suggest - besides better styling - to use the `.on("click", function...)` way in order to ensure it works after the first time as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have a scenario that do not fit with any posted answer: multiple accordions on the same page and some other collapsible components that are not accordions (without `data-parent` attribute).

```
$("[data-toggle=collapse][data-parent]").click(function (e) {
    var button = $(this);
    var parent = $(button.attr("data-parent"));
    var panel = parent.find(button.attr("href") || button.attr("data-target"));
    if (panel.hasClass("in")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation()
    }
});
```

This code only triggers on accordions, since checks `data-parent` attribute.
It also does not assume a `card` (or `panel` for bootstrap 3) structure, it uses the same attributes that bootstrap api.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Bootstrap 5**

Alternate solution from @awant. This time using the collapse events to disable the button. This works great with touch screens.

```
$(this).on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
  $(buttonSelector).attr('data-bs-toggle','disabled');
})
$(this).on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
  $(buttonSelector).attr('data-bs-toggle','collapse');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Bootstrap 5**

```
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed) {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that looks like a simple solution. Please explain how it works though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

As per bootstarp 3.3.6 version , [just follow structure](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist"   aria-multiselectable="true">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        collopse 1 body  here 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        collapse body 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: @Artistan This solution works properly. But it works [in conjunction the panel component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion). Collapsible blocks must to be children of the block, which has the `panel` class. You can use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37759350/6263942) as an example.

Comment: @gleb-kemarsky it doesn't. the subject says clearly "keep one group open" and your "solution" allows collapsing the only one opened "keeping none opened".

Comment: @kpull1 Thanks for the clarification. It seems that I misunderstood with what difficulties the author of the question encountered.