# Have At Least One Bootstrap collapse open at all times

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion, preventdefault

How Can I always have ensure that I have at least one accordion open at all times.
Currently using the event handling for collapse is terrible and I need a workaround.

```
$('.accordion').on('hide', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

does not work and it also has two other problems the collapse will not open again and it fires when popover and other bootstrap items that fire a hide event. Essentially this binding is useless.

Here is an attempt I wrote based on classes that I still cant get to work with stopPropagation or return false;

```
    $(document).on('click', '.accordion-toggle', function (e) {
        var $accordionEl = $(this),
            $accordionHdEl = $accordionEl.parent();

        if ($accordionHdEl.hasClass('accordion-selected')){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            return false;
        } else {
            //remove current active style
            $('.accordion-selected').removeClass('accordion-selected');
            $accordionHdEl.addClass('accordion-selected');
        }
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you make Twitter Bootstrap Accordion keep one group open?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725717/how-do-you-make-twitter-bootstrap-accordion-keep-one-group-open)