# How do you keep multiple collapses open in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap normally closes other collapses when you click on one to open it.

Is there an option or hack to make it keep the collapses open unless explicitly closed without changing the look and layout of the panel-group?

Answer (score 102):

***Update 2020***

**Bootstrap 4**

[How do you make Twitter Bootstrap Accordion keep one group open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725717/how-do-you-make-twitter-bootstrap-accordion-keep-one-group-open/49306356#49306356)

**Bootstrap 3**

You can just remove the `data-parent` attribute that is [normally used in the accordion markup](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse).

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
     ...
```

http://bootply.com/127843

Comment: Thank you, this is really helping. After heaving read your hint, I quickly found it here in the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse -> Options -> parent

Comment: Reference Link helped me. Thanks

Comment: @trusktr You may want to make it as an `Answer` as it has helped many people like myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

See this demo: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/OxbVII?p=preview

**Idea:**

Just add `data-toggle="collapse"` and a `data-target` to element, to automatically assign control of a collapsible element. The `data-target` attribute accepts a CSS selector to apply the `collapse` to. Be sure to add the class `collapse` to the collapsible element. If you'd like it to default open, add the additional class `in`.

Answer (score 6):

### 2021 here:

Assuming that you're using Bootstrap 4, you can simply remove the `data-parent` attribute from the element with the `collapse` class.

Bootstrap docs:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/collapse/#accordion-example

They use the following `collapse` element:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
    <div class="card-body">
        Some placeholder content for the first accordion panel. This panel is shown by default, thanks to the <code>.show</code> class.
    </div>
</div>
```

This subscribes the `collapse` to events on `#accordionExample`, which is the main accordion element, via the `data-parent` attribute. Remove `data-parent`, and the `collapse` will no longer close when another one is expanded.

Answer (score 2):

**Bootstrap 4**

NO NEED JAVASCRIPT

can implements many div of id `#accordion{{$i}}` each accordion only having `1 child` that referring 1 its parent

```
    <div class=""
         id="accordion{{$i}}">

        <h3 class="" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#collapse{{$i}}"
            aria-expanded="true"
            aria-controls="collapse{{$i}}" class="mb-0">
            Hai Im the clickable
        </h3>

        <div id="collapse{{$i}}"
             class="collapse"
             aria-labelledby="heading{{$i}}"
             data-parent="#accordion{{$i}}">
            <p>Hai Im the collapsible content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```