# Bootstrap accordion behavior expanding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

In the sample I tried to make showing the problem, but it isn't doing it there, but that's the code I'm using.

It's with bootstrap 3.3.1. The first section for bootstrap accordion has a lot. when that is opened and the next section is clicked to open, it will jump across the page. I changed it so the sections wouldnt collapse when the next is expanded, but this doesnt correct it. I left the spacer content, because this is where it seems most apparent.

Here's the example site where I'm having this problem http://sexypizzamarketing.com/#menu

If you click/open the appetizer category, then click to open desserts, it jumps off the page. I changed it so the sections do not automatically collapse when the other is opened, but this doesn't "fix" it.

Ideally, the section title would remain in place, and the content would be expanded downwards. It currently seems to expand down and slide up.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"    
    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      Appetizers
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" 
      aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p class="foodname">Baked Clams</p><p class="fd">Six fresh clams, tossed gently 
         with melted butter, freshly crushed garlic, with a hint of lemon, and mixed 
           with our freshly baked homemade bread....$10.99</p>
            <p class="foodname">Anti Pasta</p><p class="fd">Description Description description 
   description.......$11.99</p>
            <p class="foodname">Mozarrella Sticks</p><p class="fd">Description Description 
   description description.......$11.99</p>
            <p class="foodname">Rice Balls</p><p class="fd">Description Description description
   description.......$11.99</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
   href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
      Chicken
            </a>
        </h4>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" 
   aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
       <div class="panel-body">
           <p class="foodname">Chicken Sorrentine</p><p class="fd">Six fresh clams, tossed 
   gblahahsfsjdfklsdjfkljsdfklsdjklfjsd crushed garlic, with a hint of lemon, and mixed 

        with our freshly baked homemade bread....$20.99</p>
           <p class="foodname">Chicken Parmigana</p><p class="fd">Description Description 
description description.......$22.99</p>
           <p class="foodname">Chicken Francese</p><p class="fd">Description Description 
description description.......$22.99</p>
           <p class="foodname">Chicken City Slickah</p><p class="fd">Description Description 
 description description.......$23.99</p></div>
       </div>
 </div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
             <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
    href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
      Desserts
             </a>
         </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" 
     aria-labelledby="headingThree">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p class="foodname">Tirimasu</p><p class="fd">Like no other Tirimasu you have had 
    in your life. This will leave your evening complete...... $7.99 </p>
            <p class="foodname">Italian Cheesecake</p><p class="fd">Description Description 
    description description.......$7.99</p>
            <p class="foodname">Chocolate Mousse</p><p class="fd">Description Description    
    description description.......$7.99</p>
            <p class="foodname">Gelato</p><p class="fd">Fresh, handmade gelato, as authenic as 
    the streets of roma. $4.99</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will try a showing/hiding with pure css/html tomorrow and report back.

Comment: [Did you try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890435/how-do-you-keep-multiple-collapses-open-in-bootstrap-3)? As right now when you cick one other collapse and hence the jump. The only way to solve this is to stop others collapse.

Comment: yes I tried that on local site, but still happened. I tried the css3 show/hide, but that won't work on chrome.

However, if we stick with the bootstrap/collapsible.js , https://jordnkr.github.io/collapsible/
I am trying to switch to "Default- No animation" to get rid of that animation. will share how it goes.

Comment: GARRRRR I had an older version of the site's "menu" that was working, so I copied and pasted it. if you check http://www.sexypizzamarketing.com , it is working properly. Im going to print out the html for the two sites (when it was working and when it wasnt) and find where I went wrong, because this took a week to debug.