# Modifying Bootstrap Accordion

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I have added a [bootstrap accordion](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion) in my project.

I realise the only showing section can be closed too, but I hope that at least one section stays open in any situation. I'm not sure how I can prevent the only showing section from closing?

Comment: what is your issue than?

Comment: By default all windows can be closed (for example if there is only one window left open, others closed, the only window that's left open can be closed, which I don't want),  I want to make sure that at least one window stays open.

Comment: remove `data-toggle="collapse"`

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725717/how-do-you-make-twitter-bootstrap-accordion-keep-one-group-open

Comment: The window should not be collapsed only when it is only one left open..

Comment: Great thanks. I think so. How can I delete this post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Jonathan La'Fey, I think I'll just post his link as an answer to close the post

[How do you make Twitter Bootstrap Accordion keep one group open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725717/how-do-you-make-twitter-bootstrap-accordion-keep-one-group-open)

```
$('.panel-heading a').on('click',function(e){
if($(this).parents('.panel').children('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in')){
    e.stopPropagation();
}
// You can also add preventDefault to remove the anchor behavior that makes
// the page jump
// e.preventDefault();
});
```

It will prevent the only showing window from closing.