# Only open one accordion tab at one time

Tags: javascript, html, accordion

I have an accordion that works really well, it looks good on the site and works as it should. However, I'm trying to add some more JavaScript functionality to it, to make it more it look more professional.

Currently, the accordion allows you to have multiple panels open at one time i.e. if I open one tab, and then open another tab, both tabs will be open at the same time. And the only way to close these panels, is to re-click on the header.

What I would like is some JavaScript code that prevents multiple tabs from being open at one time, so if I click on a new panel, it should close the existing open panel first. Here is my HTML code for the accordion:

```
<div class="accordion"><b>Heading 1</b></div>
<div class="panel">
    <p class="text-light">Text 1</p>
</div>
<div class="accordion"><b>Heading 2</b></div>
<div class="panel">
    <p class="text-light">Text 2</p>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript code in a separate JavaScript file which currently allows multiple tabs to be open at one time

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
```

Not sure if you need all the CSS, but heres the CSS for showing the panel

```
div.panel.show {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Hopefully someone can help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do you make twitter bootstrap accordion keep one group open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725717/how-do-you-make-twitter-bootstrap-accordion-keep-one-group-open)

Comment: Just go through all of them, set them to `inactive` and `hide` them. Then you `activate` and `display` the selected one.

Comment: @NalinAggarwal where does the OP say he's using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To achieve this you need to reset the state of the accordion back to its original state on each click, before you set the required classes on the clicked elements. To do that you can extract functionality to set the class names in to their own function and call it as required. Try this:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');

for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
        var setClasses = !this.classList.contains('active');
        setClass(acc, 'active', 'remove');
        setClass(panel, 'show', 'remove');

        if (setClasses) {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
        }
    }
}

function setClass(els, className, fnName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        els[i].classList[fnName](className);
    }
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/5h5evjpw/)

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much! I really appreciate it. There is one more functionality I would like to add, however, I'm not sure if its possible... When you click on the accordion heading I want the page to scroll down to the top of that open accordion, so that the user can see all the content. Is this something that can be done?

Again - a huge thanks for the answer above!

Comment: Glad to help. You can do that by adding `document.body.scrollTop = this.offsetTop;` to the click handler: https://jsfiddle.net/5h5evjpw/1/

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the quick reply! I've tried that code, and it does something strange, when I click the accordion, it positions the open accordion at the bottom of my page, so I can see the header, but the text in the panel goes off my screen, any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: It's hard to diagnose without seeing an example. It's probably best to start a new question for that - but remember to include all your code and a working example if you can

Comment: Hey! Your solution worked! i just added a '+750' at the end of the code and it positioned the page to the right page - so thank you! One last question - at the moment its jumping rather than scrolling smoothly, any idea how I can slow down the movement of the screen, to give it a more smoother feel? Thanks!

Comment: smooth scrolling is a bit of a pain in native JS. Here's a working example: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13111/smooth-page-scrolling-in-javascript

Comment: Anecdote: I really, really dislike it when web pages attempt to "scroll" to a part of the page smoothy. Invariably, it happens when I'm not expecting it and after I've already tried to scroll, which ends up breaking things. @UsmanZafar

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ah okay, yeah that seems to be the problem I'm having. Anyway I can include the script for the smooth scrolling on the actual html page, in the head tag, whilst leaving the rest of the JavaScript in the external file? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your effort @RoryMcCrossan is there a way to modify this code to not collapse the `accordion` unless it is clicked. I mean i don't want to close what's opened unless someone re-click on it to close.

Comment: Hi mr @RoryMcCrossan, I want to ask, how do you add the angle up & angle down icon so that it can change? I've tried it but only the first icon changes, the icon after doesn't

Answer (score 7):

Close all opened tabs before opening selected tab. This will prevent multiple tabs from being open at one time.

```js
// Get all Accordion and Panel
let accHeading = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion");
let accPanel = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-panel");

for (let i = 0; i < accHeading.length; i++) {
    // Execute whenever an accordion is clicked 
    accHeading[i].onclick = function() {
        if (this.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight) {
           hidePanels();     // Hide All open Panels 
        } else {
           showPanel(this);  // Show the panel
        } 
    };
}

// Function to Show a Panel
function showPanel(elem) {
  hidePanels();
  elem.classList.add("active");
  elem.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = elem.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight + "px";
}

// Function to Hide all shown Panels
function hidePanels() {
  for (let i = 0; i < accPanel.length; i++) {
      accPanel[i].style.maxHeight = null;
      accHeading[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

/* Style the Headings that are used to open and close the accordion panel */
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

/* Change color of the heading and icon (on hover and click) */
.active, .accordion:hover, .accordion:hover::after {
  background-color: #007eff;
  color: white;
}

/* Add "plus" sign (+) after Accordion */
.accordion::after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
}

/* Add "minus" sign (-) after Accordion (when accordion is active) */
.active::after {
  content: "\2212";
  color: white;
}

/* Style the accordion panel */
.accordion-panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid lightgray;">
  <h2 class="accordion">Section 1</h2>
  <div class="accordion-panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>

  <h2 class="accordion">Section 2</h2>
  <div class="accordion-panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>

  <h2 class="accordion">Section 3</h2>
  <div class="accordion-panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>

  <h2 class="accordion">Section 4</h2>
  <div class="accordion-panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

When selecting one item, you just need to hide all of them beforehand.

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
        hideAll();

        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}

function hideAll() {
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].classList.toggle("active", false);
        acc[i].nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show", false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
var last;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
        if(last){
            last.classList.toggle("active",false);
            last.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show",false);
        }
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
        last=this;
    }
}
```

variable last will track the last active accordion, so you don't need to iterate every accordion and panel again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need another code for this functionality. Make sure you use the same id classes as Bootstrap recommended.

The Proper Accordion Code https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to cover the panel with accordion, so you can easily do that.

refer this

```
html
<div class="accordion"><b>Heading 1</b>
    <div class="panel">
        <p class="text-light">Text 1</p>
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="accordion"><b>Heading 2</b>
    <div class="panel">
        <p class="text-light">Text 2</p>
    </div>
    </div>

jquery:
$('.accordion').click(function() {
$(this).find('.panel').show();
$(this).siblings().find('.panel').hide();

});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/mhrjnsa1/c7fgyr6z/3/)

Comment: The OP isn't using `jQuery`.