# How can I edit JavaScript for Accordion expandable

Tags: javascript, accordion

I'm just a beginner in the field of JavaScript , so I need some expert to guide me how I can edit the JavaScript code to make it expand only one row at a time.

(Would like to make it automatic close a previous row when click another row, Right now it can expandable all row at a time)

And this is the code https://jsfiddle.net/4L4e88w6/11/

```js
//uses classList, setAttribute, and querySelectorAll
//if you want this to work in IE8/9 youll need to polyfill these
(function() {
  var d = document,
    accordionToggles = d.querySelectorAll('.js-accordionTrigger'),
    setAria,
    setAccordionAria,
    switchAccordion,
    touchSupported = ('ontouchstart' in window),
    pointerSupported = ('pointerdown' in window);

  skipClickDelay = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.click();
  }

  setAriaAttr = function(el, ariaType, newProperty) {
    el.setAttribute(ariaType, newProperty);
  };
  setAccordionAria = function(el1, el2, expanded) {
    switch (expanded) {
      case "true":
        setAriaAttr(el1, 'aria-expanded', 'true');
        setAriaAttr(el2, 'aria-hidden', 'false');
        break;
      case "false":
        setAriaAttr(el1, 'aria-expanded', 'false');
        setAriaAttr(el2, 'aria-hidden', 'true');
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
  //function
  switchAccordion = function(e) {
    console.log("triggered");
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisAnswer = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    var thisQuestion = e.target;
    if (thisAnswer.classList.contains('is-collapsed')) {
      setAccordionAria(thisQuestion, thisAnswer, 'true');
    } else {
      setAccordionAria(thisQuestion, thisAnswer, 'false');
    }
    thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
    thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-expanded');

    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('animateIn');
  };
  for (var i = 0, len = accordionToggles.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (touchSupported) {
      accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('touchstart', skipClickDelay, false);
    }
    if (pointerSupported) {
      accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('pointerdown', skipClickDelay, false);
    }
    accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('click', switchAccordion, false);
  }
})();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.heading-primary {
  padding: 3em 0em 0.5em 0em;
  text-align: left;
}

.accordion dl,
.accordion-list {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.accordion dl:after,
.accordion-list:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #5c5c5c;
}

.accordion dd,
.accordion__panel {
  background-color: #E3F2FD;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.accordion p {
  padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
}

.accordion {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.accordionTitle,
.accordion__Heading {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 1em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #424242;
  /*  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
 transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out; */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2a54a2;
}

.accordionTitle:before,
.accordion__Heading:before {
  content: "?";
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  float: right;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.accordionTitle:hover,
.accordion__Heading:hover {
  background-color: #01579B;
  color: white;
}

.accordionTitleActive,
.accordionTitle.is-expanded {
  background-color: #01579B;
  color: white;
}

.accordionTitleActive:before,
.accordionTitle.is-expanded:before {
  content: "+";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  transform: rotate(-225deg);
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.accordionItem {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 50em;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .accordionItem {
    /*max-height: 15em;*/
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.25s;
    transition: max-height 0.25s;
  }
}

.accordionItem.is-collapsed {
  max-height: 0;
}

.no-js .accordionItem.is-collapsed {
  max-height: auto;
}

.animateIn {
  -webkit-animation: accordionIn 0.45s normal ease-in-out both 1;
  animation: accordionIn 0.45s normal ease-in-out both 1;
}

.animateOut {
  -webkit-animation: accordionOut 0.45s alternate ease-in-out both 1;
  animation: accordionOut 0.45s alternate ease-in-out both 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(38px);
    transform: translateY(38px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(38px);
    transform: translateY(38px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
    /*
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
            transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
            transform-origin: 50% 0; */
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
  }
}

@keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="heading-primary">Q&A</h3>
  <div class="accordion">
    <dl>
      <dt>
                <a href="#accordion1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion1" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">First Accordion heading</a>
              </dt>
      <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion1" aria-hidden="true">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <a href="http://www.google.com">Test</a>adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecejusto dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris. </p>
        <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla feugiat, mauris risus condimentum massa, at elementum r. Quisque blandit adipiscing erat vitae dapibus. Nulla aliquam magna nec elementum tincidunt.</p>
        <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla </p>
      </dd>
      <dt>
                <a href="#accordion1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion1" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">Second Accordion heading</a>
              </dt>
      <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion1" aria-hidden="true">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <a href="http://www.google.com">Test</a>adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecenas sollicitudin eros in quam imperdiet placerat. Cras justo purus, rhoncus
          nec lobortis ut, iaculis vel ipsum. Donec dignissim arcu nec elit faucibus condimentum. Donec facilisis consectetur enim sit amet varius. Pellentesque justo dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris. </p>
        <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla feugiat, mauris risus condimentum massa, at elementum libero quam ac ligula. Pellentesque at rhoncus dolor. Duis porttitor nibh ut lobortis aliquam. Nullam eu dolor venenatis mauris placerat tristique eget
          id dolor. Quisque blandit adipiscing erat vitae dapibus. Nulla aliquam magna nec elementum tincidunt.</p>
      </dd>
      <dt>
                <a href="#accordion1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion1" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">Third Accordion heading</a>
              </dt>
      <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion1" aria-hidden="true">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <a href="http://www.google.com">Test</a>adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecenas sollicitudin eros in quam imperdiet placerat. Cras justo purus, rhoncus
          nec lobortis ut, iaculis vel ipsum. Donec dignissim arcu nec elit faucibus condimentum. Donec facilisis consectetur enim sit amet varius. Pellentesque justo dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris. </p>
        <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla feugiat, mauris risus condimentum massa, at elementum libero quam ac ligula. Pellentesque at rhoncus dolor. Duis porttitor nibh ut lobortis aliquam. Nullam eu dolor venenatis mauris placerat tristique eget
          id dolor. Quisque blandit adipiscing erat vitae dapibus. Nulla aliquam magna nec elementum tincidunt.</p>
      </dd>


    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of toggling 'is-collapsed' and 'is-expanded' only on the currently-clicked element, explicitly turn on 'is-collapsed' and off 'is-expanded' on all the elements, then expand the clicked element.

Comment: Incidentally, your code could be simplified significantly by using only one class (either 'is-expanded' or 'is-collapsed'); treat the other state as the default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only open one accordion tab at one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745154/only-open-one-accordion-tab-at-one-time)

Comment: @DanielBeck Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @DanielBeck that your code can be simplified further and the typical approach is to collapse all the items and then expand the currently clicked item.

However here is another approach:
You can keep a reference to expanded element and collapse it before expanding a new one. Like this:

```js
//uses classList, setAttribute, and querySelectorAll
//if you want this to work in IE8/9 youll need to polyfill these
(function() {
  var d = document,
    accordionToggles = d.querySelectorAll('.js-accordionTrigger'),
    setAria,
    setAccordionAria,
    switchAccordion,
    touchSupported = ('ontouchstart' in window),
    pointerSupported = ('pointerdown' in window);

  skipClickDelay = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.click();
  }

  setAriaAttr = function(el, ariaType, newProperty) {
    el.setAttribute(ariaType, newProperty);
  };
  setAccordionAria = function(el1, el2, expanded) {
    switch (expanded) {
      case "true":
        setAriaAttr(el1, 'aria-expanded', 'true');
        setAriaAttr(el2, 'aria-hidden', 'false');
        break;
      case "false":
        setAriaAttr(el1, 'aria-expanded', 'false');
        setAriaAttr(el2, 'aria-hidden', 'true');
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
  //function
var expanded;
switchAccordion = function(e) {
    console.log("triggered");
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisAnswer = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    var thisQuestion = e.target;
    if(expanded) {
        setAccordionAria(expanded, thisAnswer, 'false');
        expanded.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
        expanded.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
        var expandedAns = expanded.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
        expandedAns.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
        expandedAns.classList.toggle('is-expanded');

        expandedAns.classList.toggle('animateIn');
        if(expanded == thisQuestion){
            expanded = undefined;
            return;
        }
    }

    if(thisAnswer.classList.contains('is-collapsed')) {
        setAccordionAria(thisQuestion, thisAnswer, 'true');
        expanded = thisQuestion;
    } else {
        setAccordionAria(thisQuestion, thisAnswer, 'false');
    }
    thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
    thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-expanded');

    thisAnswer.classList.toggle('animateIn');
};
  for (var i = 0, len = accordionToggles.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (touchSupported) {
      accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('touchstart', skipClickDelay, false);
    }
    if (pointerSupported) {
      accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('pointerdown', skipClickDelay, false);
    }
    accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('click', switchAccordion, false);
  }
})();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.heading-primary {
  padding: 3em 0em 0.5em 0em;
  text-align: left;
}

.accordion dl,
.accordion-list {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.accordion dl:after,
.accordion-list:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #5c5c5c;
}

.accordion dd,
.accordion__panel {
  background-color: #E3F2FD;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.accordion p {
  padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
}

.accordion {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.accordionTitle,
.accordion__Heading {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 1em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #424242;
  /*  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
 transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out; */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2a54a2;
}

.accordionTitle:before,
.accordion__Heading:before {
  content: "?";
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  float: right;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.accordionTitle:hover,
.accordion__Heading:hover {
  background-color: #01579B;
  color: white;
}

.accordionTitleActive,
.accordionTitle.is-expanded {
  background-color: #01579B;
  color: white;
}

.accordionTitleActive:before,
.accordionTitle.is-expanded:before {
  content: "+";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  transform: rotate(-225deg);
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.accordionItem {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 50em;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .accordionItem {
    /*max-height: 15em;*/
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.25s;
    transition: max-height 0.25s;
  }
}

.accordionItem.is-collapsed {
  max-height: 0;
}

.no-js .accordionItem.is-collapsed {
  max-height: auto;
}

.animateIn {
  -webkit-animation: accordionIn 0.45s normal ease-in-out both 1;
  animation: accordionIn 0.45s normal ease-in-out both 1;
}

.animateOut {
  -webkit-animation: accordionOut 0.45s alternate ease-in-out both 1;
  animation: accordionOut 0.45s alternate ease-in-out both 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(38px);
    transform: translateY(38px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(38px);
    transform: translateY(38px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
    /*
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
            transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
            transform-origin: 50% 0; */
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
  }
}

@keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="heading-primary">Q&A</h3>
  <div class="accordion">
    <dl>
      <dt>
                <a href="#accordion1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion1" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">First Accordion heading</a>
              </dt>
      <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion1" aria-hidden="true">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <a href="http://www.google.com">Test</a>adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecejusto dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris. </p>
        <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla feugiat, mauris risus condimentum massa, at elementum r. Quisque blandit adipiscing erat vitae dapibus. Nulla aliquam magna nec elementum tincidunt.</p>
        <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla </p>
      </dd>
      <dt>
                <a href="#accordion1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion1" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">Second Accordion heading</a>
              </dt>
      <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion1" aria-hidden="true">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <a href="http://www.google.com">Test</a>adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecenas sollicitudin eros in quam imperdiet placerat. Cras justo purus, rhoncus
          nec lobortis ut, iaculis vel ipsum. Donec dignissim arcu nec elit faucibus condimentum. Donec facilisis consectetur enim sit amet varius. Pellentesque justo dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris. </p>
        <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla feugiat, mauris risus condimentum massa, at elementum libero quam ac ligula. Pellentesque at rhoncus dolor. Duis porttitor nibh ut lobortis aliquam. Nullam eu dolor venenatis mauris placerat tristique eget
          id dolor. Quisque blandit adipiscing erat vitae dapibus. Nulla aliquam magna nec elementum tincidunt.</p>
      </dd>
      <dt>
                <a href="#accordion1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion1" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">Third Accordion heading</a>
              </dt>
      <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion1" aria-hidden="true">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <a href="http://www.google.com">Test</a>adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecenas sollicitudin eros in quam imperdiet placerat. Cras justo purus, rhoncus
          nec lobortis ut, iaculis vel ipsum. Donec dignissim arcu nec elit faucibus condimentum. Donec facilisis consectetur enim sit amet varius. Pellentesque justo dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris. </p>
        <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla feugiat, mauris risus condimentum massa, at elementum libero quam ac ligula. Pellentesque at rhoncus dolor. Duis porttitor nibh ut lobortis aliquam. Nullam eu dolor venenatis mauris placerat tristique eget
          id dolor. Quisque blandit adipiscing erat vitae dapibus. Nulla aliquam magna nec elementum tincidunt.</p>
      </dd>


    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```