# Accordion don't work in tab unless i refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, accordion

I tried to insert an accordion in a tab but when i click on other menu and come back to the accordion, her javascript not working unless i refresh the page. Do you have a solution for resolve it ? It's really important for me please.

You will see the code in this following link :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58628259/15959437

Regards

```js
// Get all Accordion and Panel
let accHeading = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion");
let accPanel = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-panel");

for (let i = 0; i < accHeading.length; i++) {
    // Execute whenever an accordion is clicked 
    accHeading[i].onclick = function() {
        if (this.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight) {
           hidePanels();     // Hide All open Panels 
        } else {
           showPanel(this);  // Show the panel
        } 
    };
}

// Function to Show a Panel
function showPanel(elem) {
  hidePanels();
  elem.classList.add("active");
  elem.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = elem.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight + "px";
}

// Function to Hide all shown Panels
function hidePanels() {
  for (let i = 0; i < accPanel.length; i++) {
      accPanel[i].style.maxHeight = null;
      accHeading[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

/* Style the Headings that are used to open and close the accordion panel */
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

/* Change color of the heading and icon (on hover and click) */
.active, .accordion:hover, .accordion:hover::after {
  background-color: #007eff;
  color: white;
}

/* Add "plus" sign (+) after Accordion */
.accordion::after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
}

/* Add "minus" sign (-) after Accordion (when accordion is active) */
.active::after {
  content: "\2212";
  color: white;
}

/* Style the accordion panel */
.accordion-panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid lightgray;">
  <h2 class="accordion">Section 1</h2>
  <div class="accordion-panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>

  <h2 class="accordion">Section 2</h2>
  <div class="accordion-panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>

  <h2 class="accordion">Section 3</h2>
  <div class="accordion-panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>

  <h2 class="accordion">Section 4</h2>
  <div class="accordion-panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry i forget to tell => Hi everybody ^^

Comment: If you want to edit you question you can click on 'edit' instead of using comment. Please add the code of the link you share using the citation tag `>` in case the link disappear.

Comment: Hi @crg like this ?