# JS querySelector addEventListenerer index getElementsByClassName parent div only

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, accordion, event-listener

I have a page with some images displayed as modals inside accordions, simple 3 image across grid- works as planned click on image modal with caption and close button displayed- these are "open one at a time" accordions- if A is opened B closes / if B is opened A closes / so only 1 accordion is expanded at a time

no navigation I used W3 schools CSS and JS samples to put together to achieve and works as I intended-

I needed navigation for the images once clicked simple back/forward/exit  (or the square space grid gallery function)

I have been able to achieve the navigation function with JS query indexing a UL/list

However all images present on the page are indexed, and displayed instead of only the images inside the accordion

Symptoms:

-Accordion A has 10 images

-Accordion B has 7 images

-Accordion C has 9 images

26 images are indexed and cycled thru no matter what image or what accordion is clicked on-

Desired results:

After an image is clicked inside accordion B  modal pops up with navigation cycling thru only the 7 images inside Accordion B  and the navigation  stops once last image is reached.

The same for the other images inside the other accordions, regardless of number of images and position in document, only the images contained within that accordion are cycled.

```js
    <!-- !######JS added condensed from external sources#######! -->
   
        console.log("working accordion test env4");

        // this one toggles only one open at a time
        // Ref  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745154/only-open-one-accordion-tab-at-one-time

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
            var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
            var panel = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");

            for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
                acc[i].onclick = function () {
                    var setClasses = !this.classList.contains("active");
                    setClass(acc, "active", "remove");
                    setClass(panel, "show", "remove");

                    if (setClasses) {
                        this.classList.toggle("active");
                        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
                    }
                };
            }

            function setClass(els, className, fnName) {
                for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
                    els[i].classList[fnName](className);
                }
            }
        });

// acoordion sub is next 

  

    <!-- !######JS added condensed from external sources#######! -->
    
        // accordion sub

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
            var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordionsub");
            var panel = document.getElementsByClassName("panelsub");

            for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
                acc[i].onclick = function () {
                    var setClasses = !this.classList.contains("active");
                    setClass(acc, "active", "remove");
                    setClass(panel, "show", "remove");

                    if (setClasses) {
                        this.classList.toggle("active");
                        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
                    }
                };
            }

            function setClass(els, className, fnName) {
                for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
                    els[i].classList[fnName](className);
                }
            }
        });
   
    <!-- !######JS added condensed from external sources#######! -->
   
        // Modal Image Gallery
        function onClick(element) {
            document.getElementById("img01").src = element.src;
            document.getElementById("modal01").style.display = "block";
            var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

            captionText.innerHTML = element.alt;
        }

        // create references to the modal...
        const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
        // to all images -- note I'm using a class!
        const images = document.getElementsByClassName("myImages");
        // the image in the modal
        const modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
        // and the caption in the modal
        const captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

        // Go through all of the images with our custom class
        for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            let img = images[i];
            // and attach our click listener for this image.
            img.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
                openModal(i);
            });
        }

        // Function to open modal
        function openModal(index) {
            console.log("index", index);
            modal.dataset.index = index;
            modal.classList.add("open");
            modalImg.src = images[index].src;
            captionText.innerHTML = images[index].alt;
        }

        document.querySelector(".prev").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            const index =
                modal.dataset.index === "0" ? images.length - 1 : +modal.dataset.index - 1;
            openModal(index);
        });
        document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            openModal((+modal.dataset.index + 1) % images.length);
        });
   
    <!-- !######JS added condensed from external sources#######! -->




   
        /* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its dropdown content - This allows the user to have multiple dropdowns without any conflict */
        var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
            dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
                Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-container")).forEach(
                    (el) => {
                        if (el !== dropdownContent) el.style.display = "none";
                    }
                );

                //show the div that the user selected
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;

                if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
                    dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
                }
            });
        }
```

```css
/* Style the element that is used to open and close the accordion class */
p.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* Add a background color to the accordion if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
p.accordion.active,
p.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
p.accordion:after {
  content: "\2795";
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

/* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
p.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2796";
}

/* Style the element that is used for the panel class */

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div.panel.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 15000px;
  /* Whatever you like, as long as its more than the height of the content (on all screen sizes) */
}

/* end of accordion */
/* SUB ACCORDION START */

/* Style the element that is used to open and close the accordionsub class */
p.accordionsub {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* Add a background color to the accordionsub if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
p.accordionsub.active,
p.accordionsub:hover {
  background-color: rgb(113, 113, 113);
}

/* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
p.accordionsub:after {
  content: "\2795";
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

/* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
p.accordionsub.active:after {
  content: "\2796";
}

/* Style the element that is used for the panel class */

div.panelsub {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div.panelsub.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 10000px;
  /* Whatever you like, as long as its more than the height of the content (on all screen sizes) */
}

/* SUB ACCORDION END */

.alt-dropdown-hover {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.alt-dropdown-hover:hover .alt-dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.alt-dropdown-hover:first-child {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #000;
}

.alt-dropdown-hover:hover > .w3-button:first-child,
.w3-dropdown-click:hover > .w3-button:first-child {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #000;
}

.w3-bar-block .alt-dropdown-hover .alt-dropdown-content,
.w3-bar-block .w3-dropdown-click .alt-dropdown-content {
  min-width: 100%;
}

.w3-bar-block .alt-dropdown-hover .w3-button,
.w3-bar-block .w3-dropdown-click .w3-button {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

.alt-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile .alt-dropdown-content,
.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile .alt-dropdown-content {
  position: relative;
}

.w3-bar-item.w3-mobile,
.alt-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile,
.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile {
  text-align: center;
}

.alt-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile,
.alt-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile .w3-btn,
.alt-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile .w3-button,
.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile,
.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile .w3-btn,
.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile .w3-button {
  width: 100%;
}

.alt-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile .alt-dropdown-content,
.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile .alt-dropdown-content {
  position: relative;
}

.w3-bar-item.w3-mobile,
.alt-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile,
.w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile {
  text-align: center;
}

.alt-dropdown-hover:hover > .alt-button:first-child,
.alt-dropdown-click:hover > .alt-button:first-child {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: rgb(0, 217, 255);
}

/* <button style="text-align: right;"> */

.w3-bar-block .alt-dropdown-hover .alt-button,
.w3-bar-block .alt-dropdown-click .alt-button {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;

  /* prevent accidentally going back or triggering other swipe events */
  overscroll-behavior: contain;

  /* hide scroll bar */
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;

  /* momentum scroll on iOS */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

  /* disbable vertical scroll for touch */
  /* touch-action: pan-x; */
}

/* hide scroll bar */
.list::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.itemzscroll {
  height: 500px;
  width: auto;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 812px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
  .itemzscroll {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  .itemzscroll {
    max-width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
  }
}

.itemzscroll:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* hacky fix for padding at the end of the list */
.itemzscroll:last-child {
  position: relative;
}

.itemzscroll:last-child::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  width: 20px;
  display: block;
  content: "";
}

#myModal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  place-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #e8e8e880;
}

#myModal.open {
  display: grid;
}

.prev,
.next,
.close {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.close {
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.prev,
.next {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.prev {
  left: 50px;
}

.next {
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>MODAL NAV TEST ENVIRONMENT 4</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- !######external CSS #######! -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
  <!-- !######external CSS #######! -->

</head>

<body>

  <!-- !######GALLERY ZSCROLL#######! -->
  <!-- !section heading! -->
  <div class="w3-large w3-text-grey w3-center w3-bar-item">
    <P id="#prjcthead"> PROJECTS </P>
  </div>

  <!-- !accordion start! -->

  <!-- !######ADDED class="myImages" TO <li <img src #######! -->
  <!-- Group 1s -->
  <!-- !updated for accordion  -->
  <p lang="en" class="accordion" id="group1p">stand alone accordion group</p>
  <div class="panel">
    <!-- content goes below -->
    <!-- Group 1s  -->
    <!-- !drop down menu ID added  -->
    <div class="w3-col.m12">

      <div class="w3-row">
        <ul class="list">
          <!-- Column  1-->
          <!-- Tile 1 -->
          <li class="itemzscroll">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=34" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="stand alone accordion group">

          </li>
          <!-- Tile 2 -->
          <li class="itemzscroll">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=35" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="stand alone accordion group">

          </li>
          <!-- Tile 3 -->
          <li class="itemzscroll">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=36" style=" width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="stand alone accordion group">

          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- !accordion end! -->
  <!-- !######GALLERY ZSCROLL END#######! -->

  <!-- !######GALLERY ZSCROLL SUB MENU TEST #######! -->
  <!-- !section heading! -->
  <div class="w3-large w3-text-grey w3-center w3-bar-item">
    <P id="#prjcthead"> SUB MENU TEST </P>
  </div>

  <!-- !accordion start! -->

  <!-- TOP LEVEL  -->
  <p lang="en" class="accordion" id="nestgroup1p">top level</p>
  <div class="panel">

    <!-- SUB LEVEL  -->

    <p lang="en" class="accordionsub" id="group1pj">sub level 1</p> <!-- !done 9 images! -->
    <div class="panelsub">
      <!-- content goes below -->
      <!-- Group 1s  -->
      <!-- !drop down menu ID added  -->
      <div class="w3-col.m12">
        <div class="w3-row">
          <ul class="list">
            <!-- !carousel -->
            <!-- Tile 1 -->
            <li class="itemzscroll">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="sub level 1">

            </li>
            <!-- Tile 2 -->
            <li class="itemzscroll">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="sub level 1">

            </li>
            <!-- Tile 3 -->
            <li class="itemzscroll">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=3" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="sub level 1">
            </li>

            <!-- Tile 4 -->
            <li class="itemzscroll">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=4" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="sub level 1">

            </li>
            <!-- Tile 5 -->
            <li class="itemzscroll">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=5" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="sub level 1">

            </li>
            <!-- Tile 6 -->
            <li class="itemzscroll">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=6" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="sub level 1">
            </li>
            <!-- Tile 7 -->
            <li class="itemzscroll">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=7" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="sub level 1">

            </li>
            <!-- Tile 8 -->
            <li class="itemzscroll">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=8" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="sub level 1">

            </li>
            <!-- Tile 9 -->
            <li class="itemzscroll">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=9" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="sub level 1">
            </li>

          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- SUB LEVEL  END-->
    </div>
    <p lang="en" class="accordionsub" id="subgroup2p">sub level 2</p>
    <div class="panelsub">
      <!-- content goes below -->
      <!-- Group 1s  -->
      <!-- !drop down menu ID added  -->
      <div class="w3-col.m12">
        <div class="w3-row">
          <ul class="list">
            <!-- Column  1-->
            <!-- Tile 1 -->
            <li class="itemzscroll">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=57" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="sub level 2">

            </li>
            <!-- Tile 2 -->
            <li class="itemzscroll">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=58" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="sub level 2">

            </li>
            <!-- Tile 3 -->
            <li class="itemzscroll">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=59" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="sub level 2">

            </li>
            <!-- Tile 4 -->
            <li class="itemzscroll">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=36" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="sub level 2">
            </li>
            <!-- Tile 5 -->
            <li class="itemzscroll">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=37" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="sub level 2">

            </li>
            <!-- Tile 6 -->
            <li class="itemzscroll">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=38" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="sub level 2">

            </li>
            <!-- Tile 7 -->
            <li class="itemzscroll">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=39" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="sub level 2">
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- SUB LEVEL  END-->
    </div>
    <p lang="en" class="accordionsub" id="subgroup3p">sub level 3</p>
    <div class="panelsub">
      <!-- content goes below -->
      <!-- Group 1s  -->
      <!-- !drop down menu ID added  -->
      <div class="w3-col.m12">
        <div class="w3-row">
          <ul class="list">
            <!-- Column  1-->
            <!-- Tile 1 -->
            <li class="itemzscroll">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=60" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="sub level 3">

            </li>
            <!-- Tile 2 -->
            <li class="itemzscroll">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=61" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="sub level 3">

            </li>
            <!-- Tile 3 -->
            <li class="itemzscroll">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=62" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="myImages" alt="sub level 3">

            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- SUB LEVEL  END-->
    </div>

    <!-- TOP LEVEL END  -->

  </div>

  <!-- !######GALLERY ZSCROLL END#######! -->

  <div id="myModal" class="modal" style="padding-top:0">

    <!-- The Close Button -->
    <!-- The Close Button -->
    <span class="close w3-button w3-black w3-xlarge w3-display-topright" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').classList.remove('open')">&times;
    </span>

    <div class="modal-content w3-animate-zoom w3-center w3-transparent w3-padding-64">
      <img id="img01" class="w3-image">
      <p id="caption"></p>
      <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so limit the images to what you are supposed to be indexing... It is hard to tell exactly how, but you can get the images from the active panel.

Comment: that would be such an elegant way of truncating the indexing; but on the working page, some accordions have around 10 images some have over 80 images and all accordions contain different amounts of images-  let's say we designate 10 as threshold and if image 5 of 10 is clicked it would designate it as 0 and count up 9 more so it would index 5 of current accordion and 5 of the next accordion

Comment: No I am saying when you are in the modal you need to find what section is active and get those images. `var images = activeSection.querySelectorAll('img');`

Comment: I see what you mean, at least I think I do, I am just having a hard time knowing where in the code to insert-