# Bootstrap Collapse. How to expand only one div at a time

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I go about showing one at a time?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tvvq59wv/

```js
$('.collapser').click(function() {
  $(this).next().collapse('toggle');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="myGroup">
  <div aria-controls="collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" class=" row collapsed collapser" style="background: #ddd;">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">asfa asf asfasf afsf afsasf asf asf asf adf</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">test</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="text-align: right;">asf afsas afsasf asf</div>
  </div>

  <div id="collapseExample" class="collapse" style="height: 0px;">
    <div class="well">asf t1</div>
  </div>

  <div aria-controls="collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" class=" row collapsed collapser" style="background: #ddd;">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">asfa afsasf</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">test sd sdgs sd asf asfas afasf asfasfgd</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4" style="text-align: right;">asf afsas afsasf asf</div>
  </div>

  <div id="collapseExample" class="collapse" style="height: 0px;">
    <div class="well">asf t1</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do you make twitter bootstrap accordion keep one group open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725717/how-do-you-make-twitter-bootstrap-accordion-keep-one-group-open)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Bootstrap Accordion. jQuery vs HTML-attributes

There are two ways to solve your issue. You can use Javascript or assign HTML-attributes. But first  we have simplify the code.

### Start point

1. `col-md-4 col-xs-4` is equal to `col-xs-4`.
2. Bootstrap contains [alignment classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment). You can use the `text-right` class instead of `style="text-align: right;"`.
3. Note that the `.row` class has properties `margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px;`. You [need to place](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro) `.row` within  a `.container` or `.container-fluid`.
4. `style="height: 0px;"` is unnecessary. The `collapse` class set the `display` property as `none`.
5. `id` must be unique.

Let us start with  this code:

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/a5q9mgho/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.text {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.mauve { background: #c9f }
.mint  { background: #9fc }
.peach { background: #fc9 }

.text.mauve { background: #edf }
.text.mint  { background: #dfe }
.text.peach { background: #fed }
```

```html
<div id="myGroup" class="container">

  <div class="row mint">
    <div class="col-xs-4">left</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">center</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text mint">text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mauve">
    <div class="col-xs-4">left</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">center</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text mauve">text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row peach">
    <div class="col-xs-4">left</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">center</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text peach">text</div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

### By jQuery

1. Add the `.toggle` class to rows. These blocks will toggle the state of the neighboring blocks.
2. Use the `.collapse` class to make blocks collapsible.
3. The script does two actions:

   - Hide all expanded divs except the next one.
   - Toggle the next div.

http://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/73gtkvjt/

```js
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  if ( !$(this).next().hasClass('in') ) {
    $(this).parent().children('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
  }
  $(this).next().collapse('toggle');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.text {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.mauve { background: #c9f }
.mint  { background: #9fc }
.peach { background: #fc9 }

.text.mauve { background: #edf }
.text.mint  { background: #dfe }
.text.peach { background: #fed }
```

```html
<div id="myGroup" class="container">

  <div class="row mint toggle">
    <div class="col-xs-4">left</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">center</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row collapse in">
    <div class="text mint">text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mauve toggle">
    <div class="col-xs-4">left</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">center</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row collapse">
    <div class="text mauve">text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row peach toggle">
    <div class="col-xs-4">left</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">center</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row collapse">
    <div class="text peach">text</div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

### By HTML-attributes

N.B. This method works [in conjunction the panel component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion). Collapsible blocks must to be children of the block, which has the `panel` class.

1. Wrap all blocks in `<div class="panel"></div>`.
2. Use the `.collapse` class to make blocks collapsible. Give these blocks unique `id`s.
3. Add [a set of attributes](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#callout-collapse-accessibility) to each toggle block:

```css
role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#myGroup" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/L02ao1n9/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.panel {
  border: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.text {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.mauve { background: #c9f }
.mint  { background: #9fc }
.peach { background: #fc9 }

.text.mauve { background: #edf }
.text.mint  { background: #dfe }
.text.peach { background: #fed }
```

```html
<div id="myGroup" class="container">
  <div class="panel">

    <div class="row mint" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#myGroup" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      <div class="col-xs-4">left</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">center</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">right</div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="row collapse in">
      <div class="text mint">text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mauve" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#myGroup" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
      <div class="col-xs-4">left</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">center</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">right</div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="row collapse">
     <div class="text mauve">text</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row peach" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#myGroup" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
      <div class="col-xs-4">left</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">center</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">right</div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="row collapse">
      <div class="text peach">text</div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there a way to add and remove an active class?

Comment: @user1652920 Bootstrap makes it by itself. Both methods just explain to him what is required of him.

Comment: @user1652920 You can add `in` to any `row collapse` class to make that div expanded by default. I've changed code snippets in my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much Gleb!

Comment: i tried with HTML attr but can't get https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50955183/unable-to-make-only-one-collapse-expand-at-a-time/50955616#50955616