# Google Bar chart is not taking full width while in bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Google chart is not taking full width while in bootstrap accordion

I know that @asgallant has answered a version of this previously. However I can not adapt that answer to work here.

I need help with
1/ Get the second accordion to display the full width of the chart - have not found working solution
and
2/ How to colour bar with different colour based on value. I know this has been posted before but not using a google sheet as the data source.

thanks in advance
Hartmut

Web page is here
https://www.hartgoods.com/main/my-symptom-tracker/barchart-accordian.html

Code here

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Collapse</h2>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in ">
        <div class="panel-body">
        
        
        
        
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        
        <br> <br>
        
        <!--START CHART -->
<!--First Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<!--Only load the above ONCE per page-->
<script type="text/javascript">
// Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
//include extra packages that or not included in the corechart package  
// corechart package includes (bar, column, line, area, stepped area, bubble, pie, donut, combo, candlestick, histogram, scatter)
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'annotationchart', 'table']});
// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

/*
The syntax of the query language is composed of the following clauses. 
The order of the clauses must be as follows:

select  Selects which columns to return, and in what order. If omitted, all of the table's columns are returned, in their default order.
where  Returns only rows that match a condition. If omitted, all rows are returned.
group by Aggregates values across rows.
pivot  Transforms distinct values in columns into new columns.
order by Sorts rows by values in columns.
limit  Limits the number of returned rows.
offset  Skips a given number of first rows.
label  Sets column labels.
format  Formats the values in certain columns using given formatting patterns.
*/
  
/*send the query - using the "sheet" parametre not the GID parameter

The query supports the following optional parameters:
headers=N: Specifies how many rows are header rows, where N is an integer zero or greater. 
These will be excluded from the data and assigned as column labels in the data table. 
If you don't specify this parameter, the spreadsheet will guess how many rows are header rows. 
Note that if all your columns are string data, the spreadsheet might have difficulty determining which rows are header rows without this parameter

gid=N: Specifies which sheet in a multi-sheet document to link to, if you are not linking to the first sheet. N is the sheet's ID number. 
You can learn the ID number by navigating to the published version of that sheet and looking for the gid=N parameter in the URL. 
You can also use the sheet parameter instead of this parameter. Gotcha: Google Spreadsheets might rearrange the gid parameter in the URL when viewed in a browser; 
if copying from a browser, be sure that all parameters are before the URL's # mark. Example: gid=1545912003.

sheet=sheet_name: Specifies which sheet in a multi-sheet document you are linking to, if you are not linking to the first sheet. 
sheet_name is the display name of the sheet. Example: sheet=Sheet5.
*/
  
//send the query - using the "sheet" parametre - handleSampleDataQueryResponse) not the GID parameter - (handleQueryResponse)
function drawChart() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13ZXjNfFOf0glEzEkAg5VWXNTP3oZPaDR9WKwa0kTrds/gviz/tq?sheet=Sheet2&headers=1&tq=SELECT A, B   where B > 0 and B <= 5 ORDER BY B desc  limit 1000 offset 0');
 query.send(handleSampleDataQueryResponse);
}

//draw the chart -  - using the "sheet" parametre - handleSampleDataQueryResponse) not the GID parameter - (handleQueryResponse)
    function handleSampleDataQueryResponse(response){
// ADD some error handling - START
 if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
      }
// ADD some error handling - END

//get data table
var data = response.getDataTable();


//adjust chart and bar height according to how many rows
 var chartAreaHeight = data.getNumberOfRows() * 30;
  var chartHeight = chartAreaHeight + 400;
  
  
  
  // Set chart options - START
   var options = {
//set transparency of the chart background, whether the chart is stacked and importantly, 
//the physical height, in pixels of the chart.
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    isStacked: false,
     height: chartHeight,
  

 // control colours of lines NOTE this overides automatic colouring
           colors: ['orange', 'magenta',"blue"],
           //control opacity of bars
            dataOpacity:.85,
            
chartArea: {
      height: chartAreaHeight,
      top: "100",
      right: "100",
      bottom: "100",
      left: "100"
    },
/*An object with members to configure the placement and size of the chart area (where the chart itself is drawn, 
excluding axis and legends). Two formats are supported: a number, or a number followed by %. 
A simple number is a value in pixels; a number followed by % is a percentage.*/
  
  
  
  animation:{startup:'true',duration:'3000',easing:'inAndOut'},
  //makes the chart transparent so the background color shows through
 
      // chart title
          title:'MSQ Results', 
        titleTextStyle: {color: 'white',fontSize:30,fontName: 'arial',bold: false,italic: false},
       // control position of legend
          legend: { position: 'top',textStyle: {color: 'orange', fontSize: 24}},
          
           // horizontal axis title and formating
        vAxis: {
          textPosition:'in',
          title: 'SYMPTOMS',
          titleTextStyle: {color: 'white',fontSize: 24,fontName: 'Arial',bold: false,italic: false},
            textStyle: {color: 'black',fontSize: 13,fontName: 'Arial',bold: false,italic: false},
        gridlines: {color: 'white', count: 5,  units:''},
        minorGridlines: {color: 'green', count:0 ,  units:''}   },
         
          // horizontal axis title and formating
        hAxis: {
        baseline:0,
        baselineColor:'white',
        title: 'SCORE',
           titleTextStyle: {color: 'white',fontSize: 24,fontName: 'Arial',bold: false,italic: false},
                textStyle: {color: 'white',fontSize: 18,fontName: 'Arial',bold: false,italic: false},
            minValue:0, maxValue:4,
            gridlines: {color: 'white', count: 5,  units:''},
            minorGridlines: {color: 'green', count:0 ,  units:''}  },
    
     };
   // Set chart options - END
   
   
  
//draw the chart
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('mychart'));


    
chart.draw(data,options );

  
   
 
     
   
    
      window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }, false);
    


}
  
</script>
      
<div style="font-family:opensans;border: 0 none; background-color:#009688;">       
     <!-- div to show the chart on the web page --> 
    <div id="mychart" ></div>  
    </div>
    
<!--END CHART -->  

 
        
        
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
        
        
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        
        
        
        
        
      <br> <br> Chart 2






 <!--START CHART -->
<!--First Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<!--Only load the above ONCE per page-->
<script type="text/javascript">
// Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
//include extra packages that or not included in the corechart package  
// corechart package includes (bar, column, line, area, stepped area, bubble, pie, donut, combo, candlestick, histogram, scatter)
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'annotationchart', 'table']});
// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

/*
The syntax of the query language is composed of the following clauses. 
The order of the clauses must be as follows:

select  Selects which columns to return, and in what order. If omitted, all of the table's columns are returned, in their default order.
where  Returns only rows that match a condition. If omitted, all rows are returned.
group by Aggregates values across rows.
pivot  Transforms distinct values in columns into new columns.
order by Sorts rows by values in columns.
limit  Limits the number of returned rows.
offset  Skips a given number of first rows.
label  Sets column labels.
format  Formats the values in certain columns using given formatting patterns.
*/
  
/*send the query - using the "sheet" parametre not the GID parameter

The query supports the following optional parameters:
headers=N: Specifies how many rows are header rows, where N is an integer zero or greater. 
These will be excluded from the data and assigned as column labels in the data table. 
If you don't specify this parameter, the spreadsheet will guess how many rows are header rows. 
Note that if all your columns are string data, the spreadsheet might have difficulty determining which rows are header rows without this parameter

gid=N: Specifies which sheet in a multi-sheet document to link to, if you are not linking to the first sheet. N is the sheet's ID number. 
You can learn the ID number by navigating to the published version of that sheet and looking for the gid=N parameter in the URL. 
You can also use the sheet parameter instead of this parameter. Gotcha: Google Spreadsheets might rearrange the gid parameter in the URL when viewed in a browser; 
if copying from a browser, be sure that all parameters are before the URL's # mark. Example: gid=1545912003.

sheet=sheet_name: Specifies which sheet in a multi-sheet document you are linking to, if you are not linking to the first sheet. 
sheet_name is the display name of the sheet. Example: sheet=Sheet5.
*/
  
  

//send the query - using the "sheet" parametre - handleSampleDataQueryResponse) not the GID parameter - (handleQueryResponse)
function drawChart() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13ZXjNfFOf0glEzEkAg5VWXNTP3oZPaDR9WKwa0kTrds/gviz/tq?sheet=Sheet2&headers=1&tq=SELECT A, B   where B > 0 and B <= 5 ORDER BY B desc  limit 1000 offset 0');
 query.send(handleSampleDataQuery2Response); //have to change this to handleSampleDataQuery2Response when have more than one chart on the page 
}

//draw the chart -  - using the "sheet" parameter - handleSampleDataQueryResponse) not the GID parameter - (handleQueryResponse)
//have to change this to handleSampleDataQuery2Response(response) when have more than one chart on the page
    function handleSampleDataQuery2Response(response){
// ADD some error handling - START
 if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
      }
// ADD some error handling - END

//get data table
var data = response.getDataTable();


//adjust chart and bar height according to how many rows
 var chartAreaHeight = data.getNumberOfRows() * 30;
  var chartHeight = chartAreaHeight + 400;
  
  
  
  // Set chart options - START
   var options = {
//set transparency of the chart background, whether the chart is stacked and importantly, 
//the physical height, in pixels of the chart.
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    isStacked: false,
     height: chartHeight,
  

 // control colours of lines NOTE this overides automatic colouring
           colors: ['orange', 'magenta',"blue"],
           //control opacity of bars
            dataOpacity:.85,
            
chartArea: {
      height: chartAreaHeight,
      top: "100",
      right: "100",
      bottom: "100",
      left: "100"
    },
/*An object with members to configure the placement and size of the chart area (where the chart itself is drawn, 
excluding axis and legends). Two formats are supported: a number, or a number followed by %. 
A simple number is a value in pixels; a number followed by % is a percentage.*/
  
  
  
  animation:{startup:'true',duration:'3000',easing:'inAndOut'},
  //makes the chart transparent so the background color shows through
 
      // chart title
          title:'MSQ Results', 
        titleTextStyle: {color: 'white',fontSize:30,fontName: 'arial',bold: false,italic: false},
       // control position of legend
          legend: { position: 'top',textStyle: {color: 'orange', fontSize: 24}},
          
           // horizontal axis title and formating
        vAxis: {
          textPosition:'in',
          title: 'SYMPTOMS',
          titleTextStyle: {color: 'white',fontSize: 24,fontName: 'Arial',bold: false,italic: false},
            textStyle: {color: 'black',fontSize: 13,fontName: 'Arial',bold: false,italic: false},
        gridlines: {color: 'white', count: 5,  units:''},
        minorGridlines: {color: 'green', count:0 ,  units:''}   },
         
          // horizontal axis title and formating
        hAxis: {
        baseline:0,
        baselineColor:'white',
        title: 'SCORE',
           titleTextStyle: {color: 'white',fontSize: 24,fontName: 'Arial',bold: false,italic: false},
                textStyle: {color: 'white',fontSize: 18,fontName: 'Arial',bold: false,italic: false},
            minValue:0, maxValue:4,
            gridlines: {color: 'white', count: 5,  units:''},
            minorGridlines: {color: 'green', count:0 ,  units:''}  },
    
     };
   // Set chart options - END
   


  
//draw the chart
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('mychart2')); //have to change this to mychart2 when have more than one chart on the page 


chart.draw(data,options );



     
   
    
      window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }, false);
    
    
   

}
  
</script>
      
<div style="font-family:opensans;border: 0 none; background-color:#009688;">       
     <!-- div to show the chart on the web page --> 
    <div id="mychart2" ></div>  <!--have to change this to mychart2 when have more than one chart on the page-->
    </div>
    
<!--END CHART -->   

 
        
        
        
        
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: need to wait until the chart's container is visible, before drawing the chart -- also, `google.charts.load` and `setOnLoadCallback` should only be used once per page load...

Comment: Thanks WhiteHat - any hints in how "need to wait until the chart's container is visible, before drawing the chart" I can implement this within my project

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind redraw on accordion title click:

```
 $('.panel-heading').click(function(){
      drawChart()
 })
```

**UPDATE**:

I have perform some refactoring to get this work:

1. remove duplicates of script tags,
2. remove drawChart reassignation
3. add init function
4. add tab onclick handler function

So main difference:

Init starts here

```
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(init);
```

Init function

```
  function init () {

      $.each($('.panel-heading'), function(){
         var chartItem = $(this).parents('.panel').find('.chart-item');
         var chartId = chartItem.attr('id');

         drawChart(chartId);
      })

    }
```

We going for all tabs and call for each drawChart function, also to make it easier I add **.chart-item** class to chart div

OnClick function (almost do the same thing as Init function)

$('.panel-heading').click(function(){

```
  var chartItem = $(this).parents('.panel').find('.chart-item');
  var chartId = chartItem.attr('id');

  drawChart(chartId);
```

})

And last workaround:

```
 function drawChart(chartId) {
      var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13ZXjNfFOf0glEzEkAg5VWXNTP3oZPaDR9WKwa0kTrds/gviz/tq?sheet=Sheet2&headers=1&tq=SELECT A, B   where B > 0 and B <= 5 ORDER BY B desc  limit 1000 offset 0');


      query.send(function(response){
        handleSampleDataQueryResponse(response, chartId);
      });
  }
```

I refactor it to

```
 query.send(function(response){
        handleSampleDataQueryResponse(response, chartId);
      });
```

To be able pass chartId

**UPDATE 2**

To be able to manage charts in tab panels you can use *drawChart* function:

```
function drawChart(chartId) {
  var query;

  if(chartId == 'mychart') {
     query = new google.visualization.Query(' // query for chart1 //');
  }

  if(chartId == 'mychart2') {
     query = new google.visualization.Query(' // query for chart2 //');
  }


  query.send(function(response){
    handleSampleDataQueryResponse(response, chartId);
  });
```

}

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Collapse</h2>
        <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in ">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

                        <br> <br>

                        <div style="font-family:opensans;border: 0 none; background-color:#009688;">
                            <!-- div to show the chart on the web page -->
                            <div class="chart-item" id="mychart"></div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

                        <br> <br> Chart 2

                        <div style="font-family:opensans;border: 0 none; background-color:#009688;">
                            <!-- div to show the chart on the web page -->
                            <div class="chart-item" id="mychart2"></div>
                            <!--have to change this to mychart2 when have more than one chart on the page-->
                        </div>

                        <!--END CHART -->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


        <!--START CHART -->
<!--First Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<!--Only load the above ONCE per page-->

<script type="text/javascript">
// Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
//include extra packages that or not included in the corechart package  
// corechart package includes (bar, column, line, area, stepped area, bubble, pie, donut, combo, candlestick, histogram, scatter)
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['corechart', 'annotationchart', 'table']
});
// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded
//google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(init);

/*
The syntax of the query language is composed of the following clauses. 
The order of the clauses must be as follows:

select    Selects which columns to return, and in what order. If omitted, all of the table's columns are returned, in their default order.
where   Returns only rows that match a condition. If omitted, all rows are returned.
group by  Aggregates values across rows.
pivot   Transforms distinct values in columns into new columns.
order by  Sorts rows by values in columns.
limit   Limits the number of returned rows.
offset    Skips a given number of first rows.
label   Sets column labels.
format    Formats the values in certain columns using given formatting patterns.
*/

/*send the query - using the "sheet" parametre not the GID parameter

The query supports the following optional parameters:
headers=N: Specifies how many rows are header rows, where N is an integer zero or greater. 
These will be excluded from the data and assigned as column labels in the data table. 
If you don't specify this parameter, the spreadsheet will guess how many rows are header rows. 
Note that if all your columns are string data, the spreadsheet might have difficulty determining which rows are header rows without this parameter

gid=N: Specifies which sheet in a multi-sheet document to link to, if you are not linking to the first sheet. N is the sheet's ID number. 
You can learn the ID number by navigating to the published version of that sheet and looking for the gid=N parameter in the URL. 
You can also use the sheet parameter instead of this parameter. Gotcha: Google Spreadsheets might rearrange the gid parameter in the URL when viewed in a browser; 
if copying from a browser, be sure that all parameters are before the URL's # mark. Example: gid=1545912003.

sheet=sheet_name: Specifies which sheet in a multi-sheet document you are linking to, if you are not linking to the first sheet. 
sheet_name is the display name of the sheet. Example: sheet=Sheet5.
*/



//send the query - using the "sheet" parametre - handleSampleDataQueryResponse) not the GID parameter - (handleQueryResponse)
function drawChart(chartId) {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13ZXjNfFOf0glEzEkAg5VWXNTP3oZPaDR9WKwa0kTrds/gviz/tq?sheet=Sheet2&headers=1&tq=SELECT A, B   where B > 0 and B <= 5 ORDER BY B desc  limit 1000 offset 0');

    //mychart
    //mychart2
    query.send(function(response){
      handleSampleDataQueryResponse(response, chartId);
    }); //have to change this to handleSampleDataQuery2Response when have more than one chart on the page 
}

//draw the chart -  - using the "sheet" parameter - handleSampleDataQueryResponse) not the GID parameter - (handleQueryResponse)
//have to change this to handleSampleDataQuery2Response(response) when have more than one chart on the page
function handleSampleDataQueryResponse(response, chartId) {
    // ADD some error handling - START
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
    // ADD some error handling - END

    //get data table
    var data = response.getDataTable();


    //adjust chart and bar height according to how many rows
    var chartAreaHeight = data.getNumberOfRows() * 30;
    var chartHeight = chartAreaHeight + 400;



    // Set chart options - START
    var options = {
        //set transparency of the chart background, whether the chart is stacked and importantly, 
        //the physical height, in pixels of the chart.
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        isStacked: false,
        height: chartHeight,


        // control colours of lines NOTE this overides automatic colouring
        colors: ['orange', 'magenta', "blue"],
        //control opacity of bars
        dataOpacity: .85,

        chartArea: {
            height: chartAreaHeight,
            top: "100",
            right: "100",
            bottom: "100",
            left: "100"
        },
        /*An object with members to configure the placement and size of the chart area (where the chart itself is drawn, 
        excluding axis and legends). Two formats are supported: a number, or a number followed by %. 
        A simple number is a value in pixels; a number followed by % is a percentage.*/



        animation: {
            startup: 'true',
            duration: '3000',
            easing: 'inAndOut'
        },
        //makes the chart transparent so the background color shows through

        // chart title
        title: 'MSQ Results',
        titleTextStyle: {
            color: 'white',
            fontSize: 30,
            fontName: 'arial',
            bold: false,
            italic: false
        },
        // control position of legend
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
            textStyle: {
                color: 'orange',
                fontSize: 24
            }
        },

        // horizontal axis title and formating
        vAxis: {
            textPosition: 'in',
            title: 'SYMPTOMS',
            titleTextStyle: {
                color: 'white',
                fontSize: 24,
                fontName: 'Arial',
                bold: false,
                italic: false
            },
            textStyle: {
                color: 'black',
                fontSize: 13,
                fontName: 'Arial',
                bold: false,
                italic: false
            },
            gridlines: {
                color: 'white',
                count: 5,
                units: ''
            },
            minorGridlines: {
                color: 'green',
                count: 0,
                units: ''
            }
        },

        // horizontal axis title and formating
        hAxis: {
            baseline: 0,
            baselineColor: 'white',
            title: 'SCORE',
            titleTextStyle: {
                color: 'white',
                fontSize: 24,
                fontName: 'Arial',
                bold: false,
                italic: false
            },
            textStyle: {
                color: 'white',
                fontSize: 18,
                fontName: 'Arial',
                bold: false,
                italic: false
            },
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 4,
            gridlines: {
                color: 'white',
                count: 5,
                units: ''
            },
            minorGridlines: {
                color: 'green',
                count: 0,
                units: ''
            }
        },

    };
    // Set chart options - END



    console.log('chartId111', chartId);

    //draw the chart
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById(chartId)); //have to change this to mychart2 when have more than one chart on the page 


    chart.draw(data, options);


    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }, false);


  }

function init () {

  console.log('init');

  $.each($('.panel-heading'), function(){
     var chartItem = $(this).parents('.panel').find('.chart-item');
     var chartId = chartItem.attr('id');

     console.log('chartId', chartId);

     drawChart(chartId);
  })

}

$('.panel-heading').click(function(){

    var chartItem = $(this).parents('.panel').find('.chart-item');
    var chartId = chartItem.attr('id');

    drawChart(chartId);

})


  
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks also Leguest. Could you please give me some more information as where I would implement your code into my project. My JS skills are very limited.

Comment: Thanks so much Leguest. Will take a look at this and integrate in my site. Will keep you posted.

Comment: That is awesome. I have named the accordion after you!!

Comment: 1/ I would like to put a DIFFERENT chart in each panel of the accordion and 2/ would it be difficult to make each accordion panel work independently i.e. NOT act as a group - so that more than one panel can be open at a time. My apologies - I should have made this more clear at the start.

Comment: I updated my answer, but better way to put your query&options managment to different function, e.g. `query = getChartQuerty(chartId)`

Comment: Fantastic. Works a treat!!

Comment: Final thing is to make each accordion panel work independently i.e. NOT act as a group - so that more than one panel can be open at a time. Previously I could just remove the "panel-group" class and that would do it. That no longer works.

Comment: You can reffer to this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725717/how-do-you-make-twitter-bootstrap-accordion-keep-one-group-open. I hope it help

Comment: Sorry about all these questions. I just also realised is it possible to modify the chart options for each chart draw. At the moment each chart has the same styling options. Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: I will have a look at the accordion fix, I am sure I will figure it out. Also if my questions are taking up a lot of your time I would be happy to pay you something. In actual fact I would like to work with a proficient JS programmer long term on my projects. Thanks Leguest

Comment: No problem, thank to you. You can contact me in linkedin, I will update my stackoverflow profile