# How can I stop content from collapsing?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 4's collapse system to show content via a series of buttons at the top.

This is my navigation bar:

```
<div class="port-item p-4 bg-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#games">
    Games
</div>
<div class="port-item p-4 bg-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#movies">
    Movies
</div>
<div class="port-item p-4 bg-warning" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#music">
    Music
</div>
```

Below that I have the content itself:

```
<div id="games" class="collapse show">
    <!-- content -->
</div>

<div id="movies" class="collapse">
    <!-- content -->
</div>

<div id="music" class="collapse">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

Then at the bottom there is a script that hides anything that is collapsed.

```
<script>
    $('.port-item').click(function(){
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
    });
</script>
```

Everything works fine.  However, If I click on "games," games content will be displayed.  If I click on "games" again the content will be collapsed and nothing is shown.  How can I stop the content from collapsing if it is already being displayed?

Comment: Are you saying you want to prevent it from working the way it's normally intended to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make Twitter Bootstrap Accordion keep one group open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725717/how-do-you-make-twitter-bootstrap-accordion-keep-one-group-open)

Comment: @WebDevBooster not exactly.

Comment: @fubar that's an older version. I'm working with BS4.

Comment: @ConVexPrime - agreed, but is the premise not the same?

Comment: @fubar It doesn't appear so to me.

Comment: @ConVexPrime I've posted an example, based on the post I flagged as a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example will intercept the button click, and check two conditions:

1. Is the current section already open
2. Is any other section already open

If `1` is `true`, and `2` is `false`, it'll stop the event and prevent the current section from being closed. Otherwise, the `collapse` component will function as usual.

```js
$('.port-item[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function(event) {
  var target = $(event.target).data('target');
  
  var isOpen = $(target).hasClass('show');
  var isOtherOpen = !! $(target).siblings('.collapse.show').length;
  
  if (isOpen && ! isOtherOpen) event.stopPropagation();
  
  if (isOtherOpen) $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="port-item p-4 bg-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#games">
  Games
</div>
<div class="port-item p-4 bg-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#movies">
  Movies
</div>
<div class="port-item p-4 bg-warning" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#music">
  Music
</div>

<div id="games" class="collapse show">
  <p>Showing games</p>
</div>

<div id="movies" class="collapse">
  <p>Showing movies</p>
</div>

<div id="music" class="collapse">
  <p>Showing music</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  It doesn't collapse the current content.  So when the page first loads, games is shown.  If I click movies, it is uncollapsed below games.  I can also still uncollapsed everything.

Comment: Maybe I didn't specify that I only need one content section to show at a time.  So if I click games - movies and music need to collapse.  If I click games again, nothing needs to happen.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that you wanted only one section open at a time. I've updaated my answer.