# Bootstrap Accordion: Preventing the open panel from collapsing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-accordion

To prevent the currently-open panel from collapsing, I'm using [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53086434/722393). It's working in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/InteXX/cjrd72h3/), but when I copy everything to a new page it fails to prevent the collapse. My test markup is below.

Am I loading something in the wrong order perhaps? How can I use this to prevent the collapse?

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Example</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  <style>
    div.wrapper {
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-top: 100px;
      width: 500px;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    $('#accordionExample').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
      $(this).data('isShowing', true);
    });

    $('#accordionExample').on('hide.bs.collapse', function (event) {
      if (!$(this).data('isShowing')) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      $(this).data('isShowing', false);
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
          <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </button>
          </h2>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
          <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
              Collapsible Group Item #2
            </button>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
          <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
              Collapsible Group Item #3
            </button>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Am I loading something in the wrong order perhaps?"*

That was it.

I moved the `<script>` element out of the document `<head>` to the end of the page—after the accordion—and it started working.